# change color of both text and link when hovering over element

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple element which contains some text or a link.

I want to both change the text color and link color when I am hovering over the element. I can't get it to work and I assume it's because you can't select 2 pseudo-classes. How would I get something like this to work?

css:

```
.test, .test a:link, .test a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.test:hover, .test:hover .test a:link, .test:hover .test a:visited {
   color: yellow;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="test">
  testtext<br>
  <a href="#">testlink</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `#` id selector instead of class

Comment: @NenadVracar doesn't fix it. It was a typing mistake for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this using only css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hover</title>

<style type="text/css">
  body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

div.test{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
}

div.test a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

 .test:hover, .test:hover a{
  color: orange;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="test">
test text<br/>
<a href="#">test link</a>
</div>




</body>



</html>
```

or else with little bit jquery you can do more... like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hover</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

div.test{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.test a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
}

  


</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="test">
test text<br/>
<a href="#">test link</a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".test").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).css({"color":"orange"});
   $("a").css({"color":"orange"})
 });

  $(".test").mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).css({"color":"black"});
   $("a").css({"color":"black"})
 });
</script>


</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just correct path to you link:

```
.test,
.test a:link,
.test a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.test:hover,
.test:hover a:link,
.test:hover a:visited {
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtqxh0bn/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#test, #test a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#test:hover, #test:hover a {
   color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">testtext<br><a href="#">testlink</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#test, #test a, #test a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#test:hover, #test:hover a, #test a:visited {
   color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">testtext<br><a href="#">testlink</a></div>
```